# How to convert country codes into country names

Tags: r, converters, country-codes

Here's my reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)
library(countrycode)

#Query eurostat data set
search <- search_eurostat("road", type = "table")

#Accessing "People killed in road accidents" data set.
df <- get_eurostat("tsdtr420")

#Create a data frame filtered on most recent data (2015)
accidents2015 <- df %>%
  filter(time == "2015-01-01") 

codes <- select(accidents2015, geo)

countrycode(sourcevar = codes, "iso2c", "country_name")
```

When the last line runs I get this error message:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in countrycode(sourcevar = codes, "iso2c", "country_name") : 
>         sourcevar must be a character or numeric vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. pass a vector, not a data frame/tibble as the sourcevar
2. use `country.name`, not `country_name` as the destination code
3. in your specific case, you're better off using `eurostat` as the origin code

for example...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)
library(countrycode)

accidents2015 <- 
  get_eurostat("tsdtr420") %>%
  filter(time == "2015-01-01")

countrycode(sourcevar = accidents2015$geo, "eurostat", "country.name")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you gave the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `codes` is a data frame and you need to pass a vector ie use the column of the data frame. Also, change the class from a factor to a character. Finally it is `"country.name"` not `"country_name"`:

```
codes$geo = as.character(codes$geo)

countrycode(sourcevar = codes$geo, "iso2c", "country.name")


[1] "Austria"        "Belgium"        "Switzerland"    "Cyprus"         "Czech Republic" "Germany"        "Denmark"       
 [8] "Estonia"        NA               "Spain"          "Finland"        "France"         "Croatia"        "Hungary"       
[15] "Iceland"        "Italy"          "Lithuania"      "Luxembourg"     "Latvia"         "Malta"          "Netherlands"   
[22] "Norway"         "Poland"         "Portugal"       "Romania"        "Slovenia"       NA
```

Comment: Also not sure about EL, but UK should be GB to be converted correctly

Comment: Thanks for your answer!